How to set default "find in explorer" mode in VS Code?
In one of the recent VS Code updates, they redesigned the "find in explorer" feature (ctrl+alt+f in the explorer view) so instead of just highlighting items it filters the whole list, which in my opinion is way more useful, but about 2 versions later the old highlight mode was brought back and made the default again. Filter mode still exists and can be toggled with a button in the search box, but it defaults to off and resets every time the workspace is reloaded.
Is there any way to have it default to filter mode, or at least make this persistent within the workspace like the in-file find options are?
I have tried changing the option "Workbench › List: Default Find Mode" but it does not appear to affect this. Unsure if it's broken or meant for something else. I don't see any other settings that look related.

What OS are you using?

I'm using the latest version of Windows 10.

Indeed, changes were made in the most recent release group at the time of this writing.
I'm pretty sure it should be with "workbench.list.defaultFindMode": "filter",, but it looks like there's a bug in v1.96 that it's not working in the Folders View specifically (the other ones are behaving properly for me). I raised a bug ticket: workbench.list.defaultFindMode seems ignored for Folders View #236770. If you can follow the repro steps there and reproduce, give the issue ticket a thumbs up to show that you also have this issue.
There's the offchance that this is intended behaviour, in which case a maintainer will say so. I don't see anything here that would indicate that. But I'm not familiar with the source code so I could be barking up the wrong trees.

A maintainer confirmed that it's a bug and added a fix, which will be in the January 2025 release.
